# Run python script with source file

Tags: python, python-import, python-venv

i have a python script that have "import ncs". This import statement works only if i run the command "source ~/nso-6.1/ncsrc". If i open a shell and i don't run the source command, if i run the python script it says "No module named 'ncs'"

Now, i want to use the VSCode interactive window in order to run the script, but i cannot put the source command, so there is always the same "No module named 'ncs'" error.
How can i import ncs without using the source command? How can i start using it?

Thanks

Comment: From [the guide for Installation of `nso`](https://developer.cisco.com/docs/nso-guides-6.1/#!installation/local-install-steps): "*Most users add `source ~/nso-x.x/ncsrc` (where x.x is the NSO version) to their ~/.bash_profile*". Have you tried this?

Comment: That's the problem: i have to do the source command in terminal before running the script (on the same terminal). I would like to run the script that import ncs without running the source command, how can i achieve this?

Comment: If you add this command to your shell profile as I mentioned in my last comment, it should be automatically executed when the shell initially spawns (without requiring manual intervention to do so).